# Поиск символов в строке с исключениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Добрый день!
Прошу помощи, или хотя бы становления на путь истины, как сделать исключение для поиска по всему тексту, т.е.:
Этим выражением я провожу поиск символов по всему тексту

**({|})**

А это выражение является исключением для поиска:

**('.+?')|(".+?")|((.+?))|(//.+)**

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы первое выражение искало символы везде, кроме совпадений второго выражения?

Answer (score 1):

у меня работает:

```
# print 'aa { bb } " { cc }" { dd } ee " { vv } "' | perl -lne 'while (m#(?:".+?"|''.+?''|\(.+?\)|//.++|(\{|\}))#gsm) { print $1 }' 
{
}

{
}

#
```

Comment: http://s4.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/04/8af4dca63f244dece8e020d17b956300.png

Comment: ничего не понял

Answer (score 0):

(?:".+?"|''.+?''|(.+?)|//.++|({|}))

Comment: Работает, но не так, как требуется.